# Create group based on the data available in SQL server table having specific condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

There is a table which contains SQL server blocking chain data, like below.

I am trying to pull only those blocking chain groups whose average wait time is greater than 20 seconds.Group can be identified like - It starts from where it founds blocked value as 0 and ends on where it found again blocked value as 0. And last found with 0 value should not be consider in group

```
Blocking_time   SPID    blocked WAIT_MS Blocking_Chain_tree_details_by_Session_id_and_header    Wait_type
7/28/19 5:14 AM 130 0         HEAD -  SPID (130) - EL.dbo.test;1    
7/28/19 5:14 AM 292 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (292) - EL.dbo.test123;1  PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:14 AM 949 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (949) - EL.dbo.sstest123;1    PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:32 AM 106 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (106) - EL.dbo.checjmark;1    PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:32 AM 130 0         HEAD -  SPID (130) - Eli.dbo.sss;1    
7/28/19 5:32 AM 292 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (292) - EL.dbo.variable;1 PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:32 AM 949 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (949) - Eldbo.anything;1  PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:32 AM 1578    130 12000     |      |-----  SPID (1578) - EL.dbo.something;1   PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 9:20 AM 196 513 21700     |      |-----  SPID (196) - (@P1 uniqueidentifier,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P ...      LCK_M_IX
```

NA

Actual result should be like as below-

```
Blocking_time   SPID    blocked WAIT_MS Blocking_Chain_tree_details_by_Session_id_and_header    Wait_type
7/28/19 5:32 AM 130 0         HEAD -  SPID (130) - Eli.dbo.sss;1    
7/28/19 5:32 AM 292 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (292) - EL.dbo.variable;1 PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:32 AM 949 130 1     |      |-----  SPID (949) - Eldbo.anything;1  PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 5:32 AM 1578    130 12000     |      |-----  SPID (1578) - EL.dbo.something;1   PAGELATCH_EX
7/28/19 9:20 AM 196 513 21700     |      |-----  SPID (196) - (@P1 uniqueidentifier,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P ...      LCK_M_IX
```

Comment: "average wait time is greater than 20 seconds."  How is this calculated?  I just can't tell where the wait time is stored, and it is stored in milliseconds and not seconds.  Maybe if you replace the tabs with spaces, your data will be understandable.

Comment: Or lets say if any one of group contains waittime>20 seconds, need to select that group

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function for this. So long as you put your grouping columns in the PARTITION BY you'll be able to get the MAX value for the group. Then you can filter to just the groups where the max time is over 20 seconds.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  Blocking_time,
            SPID,
            blocked,
            WAIT_MS,
            Blocking_Chain_tree_details_by_Session_id_and_header,
            Wait_type,
            MAX(WAIT_MS) OVER (PARTITION BY Blocking_time ORDER BY Blocking_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) [Max_WAIT_MS]
    FROM <YourTable>
) rawData
WHERE [Max_WAIT_MS] > 20000
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not showing the whole group details and only showing where waittime >20sec. Actual required is if average(wait_ms)>20 then whole group can be in ouput

Comment: Ah yep, forgot to make sure the window was looking at all rows in the group.

Comment: What do you mean all group details? Just remove the WHERE clause and you can see the max wait time for all of the groups. If you're doing this in reporting services you should pass a paremeter for the wait time so you can let the user filter the list to what they want.

Comment: group should create as below- Rows started from word head till it will find another word head in that column (Blocking_Chain_tree_details_by_Session_id_and_header) ,It means in above data first 4 rows are one group and another 6 rows are second group

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the exact results you want please? I'm struggling to understand what you mean.